# Issue with sending a val to an input using oninput

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sSwvq/137/)

here's the JSfiddle for it, can't seem to get the read-only input to update with the val of the other input (it's going to be a hidden input)

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="otherAmt" class="qty" type="text" placeholder="Amount Hidden" />
    <p> The Costs are:</p> <input type="text" id="otherAmtHidden" name="otherAmtHidden" readonly="" />
</form>

var otherAmt = document.getElementById("otherAmt");

var otherAmtHidden = document.getElementById("otherAmtHidden");

otherAmt.oninput =  function(){
   alert('input Received');
   var val1 = parseInt(otherAmt.value, 10);
   alert(val1 + 'val1');
   var amtHidden = val1;
   alert(amtHidden + 'amtHidden');
   //otherAmtHidden.innerHTML = amtHidden;
   $('input [name="otherAmtHidden"]').val(amtHidden);
   alert('finished');
};
```

**Edit:** I'm dumb, Solved it by changing the `$('input etc').val(amtHidden);` to `$('#otherAmtHidden).val(amtHidden);`

Comment: My bad! I'll do that!

Comment: No problemo! It's just more helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb, I Solved it by changing the $('input etc').val(amtHidden); to $('#otherAmtHidden).val(amtHidden);

```
Fixed Javascript

var otherAmt = document.getElementById("otherAmt");
var otherAmtHidden = document.getElementById("otherAmtHidden");

otherAmt.oninput =  function(){
   var val1 = parseInt(otherAmt.value, 10);
   var amtHidden = val1;
   $('#otherAmtHidden').val(amtHidden);
};
```